# Devops server insallation error for Analytics and collection not working

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have installed devops server 2020.1 express
during installation I got error:
[image]

in addition, when I use the browser to go to the azure devops website, it doesn't load and after awhile i get an error 404 or 500

In addition the collection does not start (when i create a new one it fails at step 367 out of 400)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If any one gets here, I have fixed my problem with adding analytics services to SQL server

Thanks